# Android - Force PreferenceActivity to not save automatically

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have a PreferenceActivity that manage my SharedPreferences xml file.
But I want to manage that xml file on my own (load, change, save).

Can I force PreferenceActivity to not save automatically my Settings/SharedPreferences ?

I want to use that Activity only to bring my settings simple to View und get the user changes when the activity lost that focus. After that, I manually save that changes with SharedPreferences.

Comment: I recommend to not do that. The user is used to the behavior of the PreferenceActivity from numerous apps out there. If yours will not automatically save any modification it will look like a bug to the user.

Comment: I want to manage that complete behaviour by my own and the customer doesn't mind if I or the Activity saves changes.

Comment: I mean, i don't have to do that but i wanted to know, how or if that works

Comment: If the customer doesn't mind why add complexity by not using the standard API? If the standard API fulfills the requirements doing something else just adds costs and risks.

Comment: Alright, you have convinced me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set preference's attribute android:persistent="false",and then it will not stores its value to the shared preferences.